# for and while loop in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

```
for (i=0 ; i<=10; i++)
{
    ..
    ..
}

i=0;
while(i<=10)
{
    ..
    ..
    i++;
}
```

In for and while loop, which one is better, performance wise?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(update)
Actually - there is one scenario where the `for` construct is more efficient; looping on an array. The compiler/JIT has optimisations for this scenario *as long as you use* `arr.Length` *in the condition*:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]); // skips bounds check
}
```

In this very specific case, it skips the bounds checking, as it already knows that it will never be out of bounds. Interestingly, if you "hoist" `arr.Length` to try to optimize it manually, you prevent this from happening:

```
int len = arr.Length;
for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]); // performs bounds check
}
```

However, with other containers (`List<T>` etc), hoisting is fairly reasonable as a manual micro-optimisation.

(end update)

---

Neither; a for loop is evaluated as a while loop under the hood anyway.

For example 12.3.3.9 of ECMA 334 (definite assignment) dictates that a for loop:

```
for ( for-initializer ; for-condition ; for-iterator ) embedded-statement
```

is essentially equivalent (from a **Definite assignment** perspective (not quite the same as saying "the compiler must generate this IL")) as:

```
{
    for-initializer ;
    while ( for-condition ) {
        embedded-statement ;
        LLoop:
        for-iterator ;
    }
}
```

> with continue statements that target
>   the for statement being translated to
>   goto statements targeting the label
>   LLoop. If the for-condition is omitted
>   from the for statement, then
>   evaluation of definite assignment
>   proceeds as if for-condition were
>   replaced with true in the above
>   expansion.

Now, this doesn't mean that the compiler has to do exactly the same thing, but in reality it pretty much does...

Comment: Can you provide sources and citations for hoisting length breaks optimization?

Comment: @Krythic just stumbled across this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/29/for-vs-foreach-on-arrays-and-lists/ blog post from Jon Skeet.

Comment: NoxMortem Thanks

Comment: https://code2night.com/Tutorials/Article/Csharp-Tutorials you can learn through the link. in this blog the explanation is so clear

Answer (score 12):

I would say they are the same and you should never do such micro-optimizations anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The performance will be the same. However, unless you need to access the `i` variable outside the loop then you should use the `for` loop.  This will be cleaner since `i` will only have scope within the block.

Answer (score 4):

Program efficiency comes from proper algorithms, good object-design, smart program architecture, etc.

Shaving a cycle or two with for loops vs while loops will NEVER make a slow program fast, or a fast program slow.

If you want to improve program performance in this section, find a way to either partially unroll the loop (see [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)), or improve performance of what is done inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Neither one. They are equivalent. You can think of the 'for' loop being a more compact way of writing the while-loop.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are equivalent code snippets.