# how to convert the entire content of a DataTable column to a delimited string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset, datacolumn

I am retrieving data from an MSSQL server using the SqlDataAdapter and DataSet.  From that DataSet I am creating a DataTable.  My goal is to convert each column of the table into a string where the elements are comma delimited.  I figured that I would try the string conversion first before making the delimiter work.

The code runs in the code-behind of an ASP.Net page.  The ultimate goal is to pass the string to a jscript variable, it's a "functional requirement" that I create a delimited string from the columns and that it has to end up as a jscript variable.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
    DataTable temperature = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];

    // LOOP1
    foreach (DataRow row in temperature.Rows)
    // this loop works fine and outputs all elements
    // of the table to the web page, this is just to
    // test things out
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in temperature.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(row[col] + " ### ");
        }
        Response.Write("<br>");
    }

    // LOOP2
    foreach (DataColumn column in temperature.Columns)
    // this loop was meant to take all elements for each
    // column and create a string, then output that string
    {
        Response.Write(column.ToString() + "<br>");
    }
```

In LOOP1 things work fine.  My data has 4 columns, all are appropriately rendered with one record per row on the web page.

I saw the code for LOOP2 at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.tostring.aspx which seems to do exactly what I need except it does not actually do what I want.

The only thing LOOP2 does is write 4 lines to the web page.  Each line has the header of the respective table column but none of the additional data.  Clearly there's either a logic flaw on my part or I misunderstand how DataColumn and .toString for it works.  Please help me out on this one.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's an SQL query result example, this is what the Table looks like:
[Table quesry result @ ImageShack](http://img811.imageshack.us/i/queryresult.png/)

What I want to end up are four strings, here's an example for the string that would be created from the second column: "-6.7, -7, -7.2, -7.3, -7.3".

Comment: Do you want the data as displayed on the page i.e. one string per record?

Comment: Currently yes, one string per column, meaning all records in the column are converted into a single string.  The reason for all of this though is to pass that string to a jscript variable rather than response.write() it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code will concatenate values from cells under each column with `", "`:

```
foreach (var column in temperature.Columns)
{
    DataColumn dc = column as DataColumn;
    string s = string.Join(", ", temperature.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                                 .Select(r => r[dc]));
    // do whatever you need with s now
}
```

For example, for DataTable defined as:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column #1"));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column #2"));
table.Rows.Add(1, 2);
table.Rows.Add(11, 22);
table.Rows.Add(111, 222);
```

... it will produce `"1, 11, 111"` and `"2, 22, 222"` strings.

---

**Edit:** *I saw you chose to declare column as var as opposed to DataColumn, is that a matter of personal preference/style or is there an issue with coding?*

Consider following scenario (on the same data table example as above):

```
// we decide we'll use results later, storing them temporarily here
List<IEnumerable<string>> columnsValues = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
foreach (DataColumn column in temperature.Columns)
{
    var values = temperature.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                                 .Select(r => r[column].ToString())
    columnsValues.Add(values);
}
```

We *assume* we now got list of list of column values. So, when we print them, like this:

```
foreach (var lisOfValues in columnsValues)
{
    foreach (var value in listOfValues)
    {
        Debug.Write(value + " ");
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

We expect to see `1 11 111` followed by `2 22 222`. Right?

**Wrong**.

This code will output `2 22 222` twice. Why? Our `.Select(r => r[column].ToString())` ***captures*** `column` variable - not its value, but variable itself  - and since we don't use it immediately, once we're out of loop all we know is **last** value of `column`.

To learn more about this concept search for *closures* and *captured variables* - for example, in posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-captured-variable-in-loop).

**Summary**:

In this very case you can go with `DataColumn` in `foreach` statement. It doesn't matter here because we're enumerating through our `.Select(r => r[dc])` either way inside the loop (precisely, `string.Join` does that for us), producing results before we get to next iteration - whatever we capture, is used immediately.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.  I am quite new to all of this and not exactly sure why VS2010 doesn't like "OfType", here's what it has to say about it:  Error 1 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  I am working with .Net 4, the OfType seems to be pre-2.0?

Comment: Your file is missing System.Linq namespace, simply add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much indeed.  Sadly I can't vote this up yet.

Comment: Great Example +1 ill be using this in the future.

Comment: I saw you chose to declare column as var as opposed to DataColumn, is that a matter of personal preference/style or is there an issue with coding it like so `foreach (DataColumn column in temperature.Columns)
        {
            string s = string.Join(", ", temperature.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(r => r[column]));
            // do whatever you need with s now}`

Answer (score 0):

The link you have posted clearly states

> The Expression value, if the property
>   is set; otherwise, the ColumnName
>   property.

and that is what is happening. You get column names.

Answer (score 0):

This could help: [How to convert a DataTable to a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104121/how-to-convert-a-datatable-to-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Priyank, the traditional looping through the rows and columns and assembling a string from the return works, that's basically what my LOOP1 already does except it doesn't build the string.  I am trying to understand the DataColumn property and how to use it properly.