# Show the data in a dataset?

Tags: c#, web-services, dataset

I am trying to view the data in a `Dataset`, I don't mind what view it is, i can print it out in a `text file` or show it in a `Datagrid` I am just trying to discover whats in side. I am testing a Webservice to see if it returns results and i have it returning a `Dataset`.

```
ServiceReference1.PropertiesSoapClient ws1 = new ServiceReference1.PropertiesSoapClient();
            ws1.Open();

 DataSet datasetprint = new DataSet();
            if (ws1 != null)
            {
                ServiceReference1.ReturnValuationRequest request = new ServiceReference1.ReturnValuationRequest(UserID, trackingNumber);
                ServiceReference1.ReturnValuationResponse response = ws1.ReturnValuation(request);
                if (response.ReturnValuationResult != null)
                {
                    DataSet ds = response.ReturnValuationResult;
                    datasetprint = ds;            
                }
            }
```

Whats the best way for me to view its Content?

---

**Edit:**

I would prefer not just looking thought the break point as its endless with so much data i that does not make sense.

[image]

I would prefer viewing it in a datagrid or even in a Textfile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to view it without any additional code, just use the debugger to set a breakpoint after the dataset gets populated and hover over the dataset variable name, a little popup comes up and then click the little magnifying glass in the popup.

Its called the dataset visualizer, I think.

Just a note, it can timeout your debugging session and do some other funky stuff. If it times out then you won't be able to continue stepping through your code.

Comment: @Pommy And you didn't like my answer why?

Comment: No i did like you answer and up voted it, just did not understand it until MrFox gave a nice explanation.

Comment: @Pommy Cheers. I think many people overlook this nice little feature.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the looking class icon.
The mouse hover menu is comprised of the following elements:

- expand object properties ('+' icon)
- variable name ('datasetprint')
- looking glass (image)
- dropdown menu (donno what for :P)
- object type (System.Data.DataSet)
- pin icon (so the hover menu stays in place)

When you press the looking glass a datagridview opens, you can view the data here or copy it to view elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Export it to XML on filesystem and use any reader to inspect

```
ds.WriteXml("c:\\test.xml")
```

Comment: Great exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        textBox.Text += row[col] + ", ";

    textBox.Text += "\r\n";
}
```

Crude but will work.
I'm sure I had a more elegant and flexible solution using LINQ somewhere...

Try searching for DataSet to CSV, as that, at some point, will convert each dataset row into a delimited string, which is basically what your after.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is highlighted in this SO answer:
[StackOverflow: "How to convert a DataTable to a string in C#?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104159/1285450)

Basically:

```
using(var writer = new StringWriter())
{
  myDataSet.WriteXml(writer);
  Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
}
```

Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to populate a DataGridView simply assign a table from the 
Dataset to the DataGridView datasource. Example:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know what's inside the DataSet, set a breakpoint at the following line, debug, and look what's inside:

```
datasetprint = ds;
```