# How to reuse an externalTerminal instead of restarting the program in C#?

Tags: c#

So, I have made a simple calculator in C# (using vscode) and I'm experiencing a problem where if you calculated something, **you need to restart the program to redo a calculation or calculate a new thing.** But I only just want it to just run for as long as I want and not need to restart the program every calculation, I've tried to try while loops but did not think that would work. **I only need it to just do calculations as much as I want.**

Code (Does not matter that much):

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What Do You Want To Do?");
            Console.Title = "Calculator";
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (response.Contains("div") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert another number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = num0 / num1;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                ;
            }
            else if (response.Contains("multi") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert another number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = num0 * num1;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (response.Contains("add") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert another number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = num0 + num1;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (response.Contains("sub") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert another number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = num0 - num1;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (response.Contains("pow") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Insert another number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = Math.Pow(num0, num1);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (response.Contains("sqrt") == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a number:");
                double num0 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                double result = Math.Sqrt(num0);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: [Loops.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm) They should be coming up soon in your learning materials.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it would work! Sorry I'm a beginner, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while loop similar to what you were thinking...

```
using System;
    
    namespace Calculator
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    #region Existing Code
                    ...
                    #endregion
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function with all your calculation code and do something like this :

```
 static void Main() {
     do {
       Calculate();

       Console.WriteLine("Would you like to repeat? Y/N");
     }
     while (char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) == 'y');

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
     Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101534/1187282

Comment: `'y'` is a lowercase letter. `char.ToUpper` can't return that character.